# How to use EXECUTE INTO statement in db2 iSeries as400 db?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-luw

I have a procedure with the following lines:

The value of ITERATOR is set dynamically in a loop

```
  DECLARE V_LOSS_ID integer;
  DECLARE V_STATE_CODE CHARACTER(2);
  DECLARE V_CLASS_CODE CHARACTER(4);
  SET V_QUERY = 'set (?,?,?) = (select LOSS_ID, STATE_CODE, CLASS_CODE from LOSS L limit 1 offset '|| ITERATOR || ' )';
  PREPARE STMT FROM V_QUERY;
  EXECUTE STMT into V_LOSS_ID, V_STATE_CODE, V_CLASS_CODE;
```

I am getting the following error in iSeries db2 -
[SQL0104] Token V_LOSS_ID was not valid. Valid tokens: SQL DESCRIPTOR.

However, this procedure works on DB2 LUW database. Facing this issue only on DB2 iseries as400 database

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of the i-series. It helps to print the value of V_QUERY before preparing it, as sometimes things are not what you assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EXECUTE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=statements-execute) in Db2 for IBM i has different functionality.
So, use something like below:

```
DECLARE ITERATOR ...;
DECLARE V_LOSS_ID integer;
DECLARE V_STATE_CODE CHARACTER(2);
DECLARE V_CLASS_CODE CHARACTER(4);
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR STMT;
...
--SET V_QUERY = 'set (?,?,?) = (select LOSS_ID, STATE_CODE, CLASS_CODE from LOSS L limit 1 offset '|| ITERATOR || ' )';
SET V_QUERY = 'select LOSS_ID, STATE_CODE, CLASS_CODE from LOSS L limit 1 offset '|| ITERATOR;
PREPARE STMT FROM V_QUERY;
--EXECUTE STMT into V_LOSS_ID, V_STATE_CODE, V_CLASS_CODE;
OPEN C1;
FETCH C1 INTO V_LOSS_ID, V_STATE_CODE, V_CLASS_CODE;
CLOSE C1;
```